# How to use preg_replace in case of [ ] Motopress Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I have a text like this

[row]something[more]something[/more][/row].

This is generated by Motopress plugin for WordPress.

How can I remove all the [] and [/] tags from a string?

Comment: Are the tags always named `row` and `more`?

Comment: No. There are multiple cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Working [Example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/8QY#preg_replace)

```
$input_lines = "[row]something[more]something[/more][/row]";
$op = preg_replace("/(\[.[^\]]*\])/", " ", $input_lines);
```